# Sort date column and convert csv file to a time -series

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, time-series, xts

I need your help. I am new to R, I have this csv file shorturl.at/chDK9 with the "All Share Index"  from the Nigerian stock exchange, formatted in a matrix, with the months as rows and the years as columns.

I am trying to do 4 things:

1. Reshape the data, to four columns for **Date, Month, Year, ASI**
2. The period should be a date column in the format **01-2013** for **January 2013** and so on.
3. Arrange the data by the date, *oldest to newest*
4. Convert the data to a time-series type for analysis (`xts` prefarably)

So far I have solved **1 & 2** above.

Please see my code below

```r
rASI <- ASI_conv_to_USD_2003_2018   
gathered.rASI <- gather(rASI, Month, ASI, -Year)
gathered.rASI$Date <- format(as.Date(paste0(gathered.rASI$Month, gathered.rASI$Year, "01"), format="%b%Y%d"), "%m-%Y")
ASI <- select(gathered.rASI, Date, Month, Year, ASI)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I do not know what I am doing wrong, but the date column still shows as a `chr`. How do I make the date column function as a proper date?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Data:

```
Year,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
2003,104.904946,108.036674,106.6532671,106.1211644,110.6369777,114.3109402,109.7382693,120.7042254,129.0513061,141.9747008,140.2999274,147.4647619
2004,168.4931751,184.3675093,171.8948949,194.2243976,209.6846881,218.4302457,204.5201028,179.6591854,171.788925,176.3957704,175.7856172,180.1624481
2005,174.3600786,165.874575,156.2704949,165.9616111,162.3373385,162.9130468,165.5409489,177.6973735,190.975969,200.5254592,189.5253288,187.4381323
2006,184.2754864,187.0039216,184.1151874,183.9374803,195.3248086,207.753217,220.2425152,261.5902624,257.3486166,257.9713924,257.9644269,262.3660079
2007,290.763576,321.9563671,344.0977116,373.70341,397.1224052,408.8450816,422.9554882,404.1068702,405.3995157,413.592025,462.4500768,498.6259673
2008,465.9093801,564.6059512,542.1712123,511.539673,507.3090565,481.7790407,457.4977173,411.7628813,398.2089436,312.9651073,284.4105236,240.5413384
2009,151.4739254,160.8334365,136.7210055,147.8068088,203.1480164,183.6687179,169.4245226,152.975866,150.2860646,146.6946313,142.143901,141.1054878
2010,152.3225241,155.1887111,175.6850474,178.6050908,176.5795117,171.5144595,174.5049291,163.103972,154.3394041,169.2037838,167.046543,166.6141118
2011,179.0501835,173.3762495,163.0327771,164.2939247,168.9634855,165.1146804,158.8889704,141.5247531,132.2063595,139.799399,128.3830306,132.7185019
2012,133.3492814,129.4949163,132.8047714,142.0467784,142.1346216,138.9576042,148.4574482,152.9350934,167.5144256,170.2584385,170.6456267,180.8386037
2013,205.1867431,213.04438,216.0144928,215.3981965,243.4601263,232.9424155,244.1989566,233.469857,235.6526892,242.2584675,250.74636,266.2963273
2014,261.3308857,254.8076651,249.6006828,247.9683695,267.1803131,273.6744186,271.1943568,267.5533724,265.4434783,241.8539225,209.9881459,206.9083582
2015,176.4899701,152.4243544,161.5512468,176.6316031,174.6074809,170.307101,153.589313,151.067888,158.9094935,148.4871247,140.5468193,145.7620865
2016,121.710687,125.041883,128.7848346,127.5440712,140.7794402,104.7709381,89.631776,90.34052373,92.97916325,89.3927422,83.19668309,88.25819376
2017,85.43474979,83.04616393,83.42762792,84.35732766,96.74749098,108.4396857,120.8084876,116.2751597,116.1014906,120.1450704,124.20491,125.1822913
2018,145.2937418,141.8812705,136.0134688,135.2162844,124.7488623,125.4006552,121.2306533,114.014232,107.1321563,106.06426,100.7971596,102.5464927
```

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? You never actually said that. Are you trying to convert the data into an object of class `ts`?

Comment: Hi @CyrusMohammadian, thank you for responding. Yes, I want to convert the data into an object of class `xts`. I am trying to perform statistical analysis on the data. This would ideally start with a plot of the time-series.

Comment: Hi @r2evans. Noted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here might be a way out, gathering your data (i.e., changing them from wide to long), creating a date variable and only then translating the result to `xts`.

```
## This assumes that you already have written the data frame (as in your example)
myxts <- ASI_conv_to_USD_2003_2018 %>% 
## gather changes the data from wide to long
tidyr::gather("month","value",-Year) %>% 
## dmy creates the date variable
mutate(dat = paste0("01 ",month," ",Year) %>% lubridate::dmy()) %>% 
## keep only the date and the value
select(dat, value) %>% 
## sort by date (not compulsory)
arrange(dat) %>% 
## convert to xts (note that xts::as_xts() is deprecated)
timetk::tk_xts(select=value,date_var=dat)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roland. I ran the code but it returned errors. I have approached it in a different way though. 
`> myxts <- ASI_conv_to_USD_2003_2018
> tidyr::gather("month","value",-Year)
Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Have you tried `tidyr::gather(month,value,-Year)` (without the quotes) instead? Both work for me on my R/packages version (R 4.0.0, tidyr_1.1.0).